# Youtube GData Videos in a Playlist

Tags: objective-c, ios5, youtube-api, gdata-api

Good Day, I'm new to this Youtube GData api and **i'm having trouble with accessing the list of videos of a particular playlist.**

What I did first was get the list of playlist of a particular user. It returned something like this `GDataEntryYouTubePlaylistLink 0x888ea20: {v:2.1 title:Playlist Title summary: contentSrc:https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL5......92D127 etag:W/"D04N.....WhJVEU8." authors:1 categories:1 links:related,alternate,self id:tag:youtube.com,2008:user:MyYoutubeUser:playlist:PL5......92D127 countHint:7 unparsed:<media:group>}`

I've learned that countHint is the number of videos on that playlist. Now, I want to get those videos.

I tried creating a function that would do so, but I don't know what FeedID I'll use:

```
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

NSString *feedID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDPlaylists; //this was the feedID i used to get the list of playlist of a user
NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"MyYoutubeUser"
                                                        userFeedID:feedID];

[service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                 delegate:self
        didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedLoading:error:)];
```

Comment: Did you have any success here? I have also ran into this issue.

Comment: Yes, I was able to fix this before.. Will look into my code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find solution to my question. And I hope it can also help you.

In my viewDidLoad, i called loadYoutube and loadYoutubePlaylist functions.

- loadYoutube -> gives us the URL given the user and what feedID. In my case, feedID is kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads because I only want to get the playlists and the videos uploaded by the user.
- loadYoutubePlaylist -> gives us the URL of the playlists of the user. feedID is kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDPlaylists
- loadYoutubeVideosPerPlaylist -> gives us the URL of the videos per playlist.

This is how the codes look like:

```
- (void)loadYoutube
{
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

    NSString *uploadsID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDUploads;
    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"USERNAME"
                                                         userFeedID:uploadsID];
    NSLog(@"loadYoutube URL: %@", feedURL);
    [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedLoadingYoutubeWithFeed:error:)];
}

- (void)loadYoutubePlaylist
{
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];

    NSString *feedID = kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDPlaylists;
    NSURL *feedURL = [GDataServiceGoogleYouTube youTubeURLForUserID:@"USERNAME"
                                                            userFeedID:feedID];
    NSLog(@"loadYoutubePlaylist URL: %@", feedURL);
    [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedLoadingPlaylistWithFeed:error:)];
}

- (void)loadYoutubeVideosPerPlaylist:(NSString *)urlString
{
    GDataServiceGoogleYouTube *service = [self youTubeService];
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSLog(@"loadYoutubeVideosPerPlaylist URL: %@", feedURL);

    [service fetchFeedWithURL:feedURL
                     delegate:self
            didFinishSelector:@selector(request:finishedLoadingYoutubeVideosPerPlaylistWithFeed:error:)];
}
```

And here are the Youtube requests..

```
#pragma mark - Youtube Requests

- (void)request:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedLoadingYoutubeWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed error:(NSError *)error
{

}

- (void)request:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedLoadingPlaylistWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (kGDataYouTubeUserFeedIDPlaylists) {
        self.playlistFeed = (GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *)aFeed;

        NSArray *feedArray = [self.playlistFeed entries];
        for (int i = 0; i < [feedArray count]; i++) {
            GDataEntryBase *entry = [[self.playlistFeed entries] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *title = [[entry title] stringValue];
            [playlist addObject:NSLocalizedString(title, @"playlistTitle")];
            NSLog(@"%@", [[entry content] sourceURI]);
            [videoPlaylistURLArray addObject:[[entry content] sourceURI]];
        }
    }
    if (!error) {
        [self addMenuButtons];
        [self setPlaylistIndex:0];
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Success!"];
    }else{
        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Failed Fetching Playlist."];
    }
}

- (void)request:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket finishedLoadingYoutubeVideosPerPlaylistWithFeed:(GDataFeedBase *)aFeed error:(NSError *)error
{
    self.feed = (GDataFeedYouTubeVideo *)aFeed;
    [self.youtubeTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for this. Managed to get my list of playlist videos now!  The trick was passing the right URL.